# Java J2ee plugin installtion has dependency errors

Tags: java, eclipse, jakarta-ee, eclipse-plugin

**Cannot complete the install because one or more required items could not be found.
  Software being installed: Dali Java Persistence Tools - EclipseLink Support SDK (Optional) 2.2.2.v200911250220-53383ADCMoJCFjDTINGJOJBlG88h (org.eclipse.jpt.eclipselink_sdk.feature.feature.group 2.2.2.v200911250220-53383ADCMoJCFjDTINGJOJBlG88h)**

**Missing requirement: Dali Java Persistence Tools - DB UI 1.1.100.v200906070220 (org.eclipse.jpt.db.ui 1.1.100.v200906070220) requires 'bundle org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.ui [1.1.0,1.2.0)' but it could not be found**

**Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: Dali Java Persistence Tools - EclipseLink Support (Optional) 2.2.2.v200911250220-65A9AkF77g8OFL7BB7 (org.eclipse.jpt.eclipselink.feature.feature.group 2.2.2.v200911250220-65A9AkF77g8OFL7BB7)
    To: org.eclipse.jpt.feature.feature.group [2.2.2,3.0.0)**

**Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: Dali Java Persistence Tools - EclipseLink Support SDK (Optional) 2.2.2.v200911250220-53383ADCMoJCFjDTINGJOJBlG88h (org.eclipse.jpt.eclipselink_sdk.feature.feature.group 2.2.2.v200911250220-53383ADCMoJCFjDTINGJOJBlG88h)
    To: org.eclipse.jpt.eclipselink.feature.feature.group [2.2.2.v200911250220-65A9AkF77g8OFL7BB7]**

**Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: Dali Java Persistence Tools 2.2.2.v200911250220-7L7OAPFBBoPS0TBgXV1je (org.eclipse.jpt.feature.feature.group 2.2.2.v200911250220-7L7OAPFBBoPS0TBgXV1je)
    To: org.eclipse.jpt.db.ui [1.1.100.v200906070220]**

Comment: please dont give me the steps to install new software from eclipse. I know those steps. I just want to know how to solve these dependency errors.Thanks!

Comment: check out this http://trialsofmobile.blogspot.in/2013/02/eclipse.html, same issue. Hope it helps.

Comment: Why are you trying to install versions from 2009?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error by using http://download.eclipse.org/webtools/updates as repository but it did work by using:
http://download.eclipse.org/webtools/repository/juno/

Comment: You should add some context to your links.